# Download and load an SAS (.XPT) dataset from an online source in R

Tags: r, download

I am trying to download and load an SAS dataset (.XPT) from the website of the National Health and Nutrition Examination Survey (http://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/search/DataPage.aspx?Component=Questionnaire&CycleBeginYear=2009).

The specific dataset I'm interested in is `SXQ_F.XPT`. I've tried 3 methods:

1.Loading it using the url directly in `read.xport`:

```
library(foreign)

mydata <- read.xport("http://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2009-2010/SXQ_F.XPT")
Error in lookup.xport(file) : unable to open file: 'Invalid argument'
```

2.Using `download.file` first:

```
download.file("http://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2009-2010/SXQ_F.XPT", "download_SXQ_F.XPT")
mydata <- read.xport("download_SXQ_F.XPT")
Error in lookup.xport(file) : file not in SAS transfer format
```

3.Manually downloading the dataset through point and click, and then loading from wd:

```
mydata <- read.xport("SXQ_F.XPT")

SEQN SXD021 SXQ800 SXQ803 SXQ806 SXQ809 SXQ700 
1 51624      1      1      1      1      2     
2 51628      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     
3 51629      1      1      1      1      2     
4 51630      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     
5 51643      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     
6 51645      1      1      2      2      2
```

Why does #3 but not #2 not work?  How can I download and load the data using only R?

As requested, here is the output of running `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] descr_1.1.1     plyr_1.8.3      weights_0.80    gdata_2.17.0    Hmisc_3.16-0    ggplot2_1.0.1   Formula_1.2-1   survival_2.38-1
[9] lattice_0.20-31 foreign_0.8-63  sas7bdat_0.5   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.11.6         cluster_2.0.1       magrittr_1.5        splines_3.2.1       MASS_7.3-40         munsell_0.4.2      
[7] xtable_1.7-4        colorspace_1.2-6    stringr_1.0.0       tools_3.2.1         nnet_7.3-9          gtable_0.1.2       
[13] latticeExtra_0.6-26 gtools_3.5.0        digest_0.6.8        gridExtra_0.9.1     RColorBrewer_1.1-2  reshape2_1.4.1     
[19] acepack_1.3-3.3     rpart_4.1-9         stringi_0.5-5       scales_0.2.5        proto_0.3-10
```

Comment: Option 2 works perfectly fine for me. You'll have to post `sessionInfo()` to get further help.

Comment: Added results of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I've got `foreign_0.8-65`. Update and see if it's fixed.

Comment: Updated to `foreign_0.8-65` but still getting same error

Comment: Hmm (Linux here), might be a windows problem then. Check out [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-this-SAS-transport-file-in-R-td3073969.html)

Comment: Great link thanks! Adding `mode = "wb"` to the `read.xport` command was the solution. Please post so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out on [R help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-this-SAS-transport-file-in-R-td3073969.html), Windows systems have to be trained more carefully when using `download.file` certain files; this is such a case.

Adding the `mode="wb"` option to `download.file` should save the file in a format usable by `read.xport`.

From `?download.file`>`mode`:

> The mode with which to write the file. Useful values are "w", "wb" (binary), "a" (append) and "ab".

Answer (score 1):

I recently published package nhanesA on CRAN.

```
install.packages("nhanesA")
sxq_f <- nhanes('SXQ_F')  ## Imports as data frame
```

Comment: That looks great. I must have missed the package announcement on Rhelp.